# MongoDb in a container seed with multiple collections

Tags: database, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to feed my mongo running in a container with existing collections living outside the container.

*docker-compose.yml* looks like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
    webapi:
      image: webapp:develop
      container_name: web_api
      build:
        args:
          buildconfig: Debug
        context: ../src/api
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      environment:
        - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
        - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5003
      ports:
        - "5003:5003"
      depends_on:
        - mongodb
    mongodb:
      image: mongo:latest
      container_name: mongodb
      ports:
        - "27017:27017"
    mongo-seed:
      build: ./mongo-seed
      links:
        - mongodb
```

mongo-seed/Dockerfile:

```
FROM mongo

COPY initA.json /initA.json
CMD mongoimport --host mongodb --db Database --collection A --type json --file /initA.json --jsonArray --mode merge

FROM mongo

COPY initB.json /initB.json
CMD mongoimport --host mongodb --db TestListDb --collection B --type json --file /initB.json --jsonArray --mode merge
```

But this doesn't do the trick as it overwrites the database with the last collection, so maintains only 'B' collection in this case.

How can I import multiple collections to one database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for that.

Also the answer shows how to configure network so the webapp can see the mongodb container.

Structure of files:

```
Web.Application
.
+-- docker_compose.yml    
+-- mongo    
|   +-- dump    
|       +-- DatabaseDb    
|   +-- Dockerfile    
|   +-- restore.sh
```

---

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  webapp:
    container_name: webapp
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapp
    build:
      context: ./Web.Application/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    networks:
      clusternetwork:
        ipv4_address: 1.1.0.1
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    build:
      context: ./Web.Application/mongo/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      clusternetwork:
        ipv4_address: 1.1.0.12
networks:
  clusternetwork:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 1.1.0.0/24
```

---

./Web.Application/mongo/**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM mongo AS start

COPY . .

COPY restore.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

---

./Web.Application/mongo/**restore.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
mongorestore  --db DatabaseDb ./dump/DatabaseDb
```